# Apache TomEE Webprofile 8 - Unable to Change JSon Rest Provider from Johnzon to Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, apache-tomee, tomee-8

I have a web application deployed on Apache TomEE web profile 8.0.12.
The application exposes a rest service that returns a json.
The default library used from TomEE is Johnzon.
I'm trying to change the default Johnzon json provider with the Jackson json provider.

To test the switch of the provider I have developed a rest service that returns a class with two strings, and one of the two strings is ignored using the Jackson @JsonIgnore annotation.

```
public class PropContainer {
    
    @JsonIgnore
    private String prop1;
    
    private String prop2;
...
```

And a rest service that returns the PropContainer class

```
@Path("config")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Stateless
public class PreferencesService {
    
    @Path("get")
    @GET
    @JacksonFeatures(serializationEnable =  { SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT })
    public PropContainer get(){
    
    ...
```

After invoking the service, the json is not formatted (the @JacksonFeatures is ignored) and prop1 attribute is in the response (the Jackson @JsonIgnore annotation is ignored). I think that TomEE is still using the Johnzon library.

Reading the TomEE documentation, the steps to change the json rest provider are:

1. create the file openejb-jar.xml under src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\
2. in openejb-jar.xml file specify the Jackson provider

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <openejb-jar xmlns="http://www.openejb.org/openejb-jar/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openejb.org/openejb-jar/1.1">
       <pojo-deployment class-name="jaxrs-application">
          <properties>
             cxf.jaxrs.providers = com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
          </properties>
       </pojo-deployment>
    </openejb-jar>
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you for the support.

Answer (score 3):

I think I have found a solution creating a class with the Provider annotation.

The opnejb-jar.xml is not necessary.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MyDefaultJsonRestProvider extends JacksonJsonProvider {
    
}
```